# Laravel - Reading data from cache file inside GlobalScope apply function

Tags: php, caching, eloquent, laravel-5.7, global-scope

I am trying to read some data from cached filed previously stored after user has logged in.

If `auth()->attempt($credentials)` passes i store some users data to cache file.

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$user = User::with(['roles.perms','offices.clients','offices.locations.country'])->find($user_id);
cache()->put('user_'.$user_id.'_data',$user,60);
```

I want to use that cache file so I don't have to rerun some queries to get ID-s related for this user and its relations with other models.

So I am trying to read from that file inside GlobalScope apply function, lets say I want to display countries where the user have offices.

I tried this:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model){
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = cache()->get('user_'.$user_id.'_data');
    $countries = [];
    foreach ($user->offices as $office){
        $countries[] = $office->locations[0]->country_id;
    }
    $builder->whereIn($model->getTable().'.id',$countries);
}
```

If the cache is empty, it returns error "**Trying to get property 'offices' of non-object**".

If I turn off the global scope, log in, and then turn scope back, it works. So the cache file is created after login.

If I clear the cache and try to log in (with global scope) I get the error. So I am not sure, but I think somehow adding global scope executes before caching after login.

Any ideas how can I fix this or modify the procedure.

**UPDATED**

It looks like it took some time to create the file and global scope to read from it. I check if there is a file already, if not to create it. After this modification its working...

I used Model to create cache file not auth controller like I did before.

```
if($id=auth()->user()->id){
   if(!Cache::has('user_'.$id.'_data')){
                $user = User::with(['roles.perms','clients','offices.users','offices.employees','offices.clients.clientUsers','offices.locations.country','offices.projects.jobOrders'])->find($id);
                Cache::forever('user_'.$id.'_data',$user);
            }
            if(!auth()->user()->hasRole(['dekra_master_admin'])) {
                static::addGlobalScope(new EmployeeScope);
            }
        }
```